# XAML ComboBox Hover Effect

Tags: c#, xaml, coding-style, combobox

[image]

A XAML ComboBox looks like the above image, and when you hover over it it gets this blue hi-lighted effect as seen in the second picture. I have tried everything I can think of to remove this effect including these....

```
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF0B6529" />
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#FF0B6529" />
```

...but nothing seems to work. Normally I don't mind and just stick with it, but due to the colour scheme of the application I am currently developing it looks very out of place.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a custom Style/Template for the ComboBox. You have an example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/53134b87-1a99-4998-a1fb-b3d8a9bd2773). You'll have to modify(or remove) this trigger:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate">
  ... ...
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBackgroundBrush}"/>
      </Trigger>
           ... ...
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```